# How to enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

When I run a query with OPENROWSET in SQL Server 2000 it works.

But the same query in SQL Server 2008 generates the following error:

> SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure

i try to run

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

But any attempt to run **`RECONFIGURE`** gives the error:

```
Msg 5808, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ad hoc update to system catalogs is not supported.
```

How do i enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries in SQL Server 2008 R2?

**Note**: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)   Jun 11 2012 16:41:53   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here:
http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/database-design/error-message-ad-hoc-update-to-system-catalogs-is-not-supported/

Either run this first:

```
EXEC sp_configure ‘allow updates’, 0
RECONFIGURE
```

or change your `RECONFIGURE` statements to `RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE`:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE --really reconfigure
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE --really reconfigure
GO
```